# File template in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to create file template as to add it to a list specified under File/New File or Project?

What I mean by this is that I'd like to have some file template customized by myself like for example main.cpp which isn't there and every time I create new project I have to type (well copy because I do have it in notepad already) all structure of it manualy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read here about `Class Wizards` and `Project Wizards`
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-project-wizards.html

Comment: Link is dead. Current actual link is http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html